# Regex to match Longitude and Latitude

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to validate inputs that can be altered by users in one shape way form or another. That are specific to longitude and latitude. So I am trying to come up with a regex that will validate the entry. So I can throw an exception if it doesnt match

The regex I am playing with via php preg_match is:

```
preg_match('/^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$/')
```

which doesn't seem to work for me. I am trying to catch gps long/lat in the format like
-101.3335 and 71.5555 (of course I dunno how valid those specific numbers are but thats the general format)

Comment: How do you mean "doesn't seem to work"? That regex looks like it should work for strings like `-123.456,123.456`. What input strings are you finding don't match?

Comment: You know what, I think I just realized my issue. Its the fact I am passing them individually rather than combined, and I didn't even think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$/')
```

Is actually a working concept. When I posted, and was having trouble with it I was initally failing to realize I couldn't put one or the other as far as long/lat goes in. I would have to put them both in delimited by a , to get it to validate. Which someone pointed out in my comments to the inital post, I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/^(\\-?\\d+[.\\d]+),?\\s*(\\-?\\d+[.\\d]+)?$/')
```

Comment: This won't work - `[.\d+]` matches one instance of a `.` or a digit or a '+'